# Calling php functions in the same file using javascript switch statements

Tags: javascript, php

I have following code,

```
<script>
function sort(){
var e = document.getElementById("sort_review");
var value_review = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

switch (value_review) {
    case 1:
       <?php  not_sorted();?>;
        break;
    case 2:
       <?php  sort_by_featured();?>;
        break;
    case 3:
        <?php  sort_by_topcon();?>;
        break;
    case 4:
        <?php  sort_by_date();?>;
        break;

}
}
</script>
```

This code doesn't work as expected. How can I modify this, to call functions in same file which this code included?

Comment: PHP and js can't be interwoven like that.... PHP executes server side, and execution has completed __and terminated__ before the js even gets to start running

Comment: U can use ajax if You wan`t to use PHP inside javascript

Comment: If the data is already in the browser you might want to sort it with javascript instead of an ajax call to the server.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is executed first, then the page is sent to the web browser where the javascript is executed.

What you can actually do is, based on the option you select from your select box, send the wanted value via GET or POST method to the same (php) page, and then have the page loaded with the new value/function executed.

Comment: Actually this is a review site. People add reviews , In this page we can see reviews.  Review details are gained as a xml file.using php simplexml_load_string object. That part is ok. I want to display those reviews based on specific criterias(SORT). Can you tell me is there any away to call those functions inside switch statment using $,ajax() method?

Comment: You can send the sorting method name required to the PHP page, and have it `echo` back the html content of the sorted review. Then all you have to do is set it in the _div_ tag that is currently showing the reviews.